# Adding a column to a data frame with a distinct value per group

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
i grp val
1  x  900
2  x  800
3  x  700
1  y  500
2  y  400
3  y  300
```

Now, I want to add an extra column to the data frame that stores the same value for all rows that are within the same `grp`. More precisely, the value should be `val` taken from the row of the corresponding group with `i == 2`.

```
i grp val val_of_2
1  x  900      800
2  x  800      800
3  x  700      800
1  y  500      400
2  y  400      400
3  y  300      400
```

I thought of something like `ddply(df, "grp", transform, val_of_2 = <select val where i == 2>)`. However, I have not come up with a valid formulation so far.

Comment: Try `df1 %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate(val_of_2 = val[i==2])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `ddply` would be

```
plyr::ddply(df, "grp", transform, val_of_2 = val[i==2])
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(grp) %>%
   mutate(val_of_2 = val[i==2])
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups: grp [2]
#      i grp     val val_of_2
#   <int> <chr> <int>    <int>
#1     1 x       900      800
#2     2 x       800      800
#3     3 x       700      800
#4     1 y       500      400
#5     2 y       400      400
#6     3 y       300      400
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you point me to where this syntax (`val[i==2]`) is documented, so that I can help myself in future? The [transform](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/transform) documentation doesn't seem to include details on the possible expressions.

Comment: @user1494080 It is the common syntax for subsetting.  Here, in each group there is only a single 2 for 'i'.  Therefore we use the `==` and it returns a logical TRUE/FALSE vector.  Subsetting the 'val' based on the logical vector gives 1 for each of the 'grp' elements 'x' and 'y'.  As it is `mutate`, this value gets recycled for the rest of the rows in each group

Comment: Why do we need `mutate` here? Replacing `mutate` with `transform` gives incorrect results. I thought the only difference between both is that `mutate` allows us to refer to columns just created. Hence, I expected them to behave identically in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
ave(df$val * (df$i == 2), df$grp, FUN = max)
#[1] 800 800 800 400 400 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're a fan of SQL join logic:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- frame_data(
    ~i, ~grp, ~val,
    1,  "x",  900,
    2,  "x",  800,
    3,  "x",  700,
    1,  "y",  500,
    2,  "y",  400,
    3,  "y",  300
)

df %>%
    left_join(
        df %>%
            filter(i == 2) %>%
            select(grp, val)
        , by = "grp")
```